# Dataset[Seq[(String, String, String)]] to Dataset[(String, String, String)]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset

I am having a Cassandra table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE myKeyspace.myTable (
  rowkey text,
  columnname text,
  columnvalue text,
  PRIMARY KEY (rowkey, columnname)
  )
```

I wish to insert data in the same with Spark Cassandra connector.

My Spark Dataset is of type `Dataset[Seq[(String, String, String)]]`.

I want to convert it to `Dataset[(String, String, String)]` so that it can be inserted in the table using `.rdd.saveToCassandra` API.

Please assist on the conversion or is there a direct way to use the same `Dataset[Seq[(String, String, String)]]`.

Comment: can you please add printSchema of Dataset[Seq([String,String,String])]

Comment: I am not sure for downvote. I needed some details added comment.

Comment: can you check below answer & see if it helps ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `flatMap` on `Dataset[Seq[(String, String, String)]]`, Check below & Please let me know if not working.

```
scala> dds
res124: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Seq[(String, String, String)]] = [value: array<struct<_1:string,_2:string,_3:string>>]

scala> dds.printSchema
root
 |-- value: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _3: string (nullable = true)


scala> dds.flatMap(d => d)
res126: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(String, String, String)] = [_1: string, _2: string ... 1 more field]
```

Comment: Done, Thank You. also can you please check your other question if it helps upvote ?

Comment: Checked the other question, I edited the question, the solution does not work on Dataset[mutable.Iterable[...]]

Comment: that question & this question both are same ?